# JSF and RichFaces to validate input boxes real time

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, richfaces

Im new to to this technology and would like know if there are any function in JSF or Richfaces that will handle the validation of 2 input boxes real time.

For example I have Inputbox1 and Inputbox2, if I enter amount on Inputbox1, it will automatically erase or blank Inputbox2 and vice versa.  At the same time it will automatically calculate the footer totals.

How can I approach this kind of validation?

Comment: You may need to use a4j and cleanup the other inputbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side validation for that
http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=clientValidation&skin=emeraldTown